# iPhone, is Reset Network settings necessary after a Carrier profile install?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

My phone carrier requested an update of the Carrier Profile (Delete + Install).

They suggested also to perform a Reset Network settings after the profile installation.

Is it really necessary?

I don't mind doing a reset-network, but among the things the reset does, all Wi-Fi passwords are deleted as well, which is annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you don't have to reset the network settings.** Your phone carrier is just being thorough, as updating the profile can result in some unexpected behaviour for some users and resetting network settings usually resolves this.

I've personally only ever had to reset network settings once on an iPhone after a profile update, so you can just install the new profile and reset network settings afterwards if you start noticing some weird behaviour.